# What does this Ghostscript error message mean?

Tags: ghostscript

I get this error message from a Ghostscript call:

```
Error: /syntaxerror in -file-
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--     2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
  --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   1925   1   3   %oparray_
pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostr
ingval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 215
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Does it mean that there is problem in the input Postscript file or does it mean something is wrong with my call or the installation?

The call was:

```
ps2pdf book.ps book.pdf
```

The input file book.ps exists in the current directory.

Is there a list of Ghostscript error messages and what they mean somewhere? (Google was not my friend in this case.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a *Ghostscript* error message, its a PostScript error message. The PostScript error messages are defined in the PostScript Language Reference Manual. Syntaxerror means pretty much what it says, the PostScript program contained a syntax error.

Things you can try:

1. Execute Ghostscript on the PostScript file to render the page, does it work ? (You don't say what OS you are suing but something like `gs book.ps` ought to work)
2. Try using Ghostscript directly instead of the ps2pdf script which merely wraps it. Again something like `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o book.pdf book.ps`

One of these may help by either working or giving more explicit errors.

Comment: Thank you KenS. Both trials lead to the same error message. So I assume, the PostScript file is corrupt. It was created from Adobe FrameMaker 10 when I tried to save a large book as PDF. I have already tried the usual things like converting to current version, optimizing the files, printing instead of saving etc. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: If you can make the file public I can look at it for you. You can email it to 'ken at spamcop dot net' if its of a reasonable size (or send me email with a link). I can't really offer any help without seeing the file I'm afraid. It may be a problem in the file or a Ghostscript bug, no way to tell without seeing the PostScript program.